# How do I share stdout between multiple processes?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, tcp

I want to receive live TCP stream, and make it readable by another processes at the same time, without saving it.

For example, 111.222.233.244:1234 streams actual time. Server supports only one connection.

TTY1:

```
$ nc 111.222.233.244 1234 | (do something here) /tmp/tcpstream &
$ sleep 5 # stream is received even if there is no process that reads it
$ cat /tmp/tcpstream # it can also be like `(some command) | cat -`
17:00:06
17:00:07
17:00:08
17:00:09
17:00:10
17:00:11
```

TTY2 (second `cat` executed 9 seconds after executing `nc`):

```
$ cat /tmp/tcpstream
17:00:09
17:00:10
17:00:11
```

Comment: I don't know how you can clone output.. but you can write the output to a fifo, and make a tee there.. so stopping a process to add a new one will not loose data.. 
or start many tees sending data to manypipes and reading from there

Comment: @BrenoZan I've tried, but tee freezes nc (or hides it's output) until some process connects to fifo. And when process connected to fifo stops, nc closes connection and stops too.

Comment: I see. You need a multi cast streaming server. [vlc multicast](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-VLC-to-Stream-Audio-and-Video-to-Multiple-Computers-on-Your-Network-Using-Multicast)

Comment: Does it have to be a named pipe? I was thinking about a solution in which a small server process reads from the first process and forwards the data to any client connected (which again could be done using nc)

Comment: @brm No, it doesn't. It can be anything what acts like a file (fifo, device, socket etc.) or a command that sends stream to stdout.

Comment: @M132 You might want to edit the question, because the answer you accepted doesn't seem to be answering your question as it is right now.

Comment: @peterph What's wrong with my question?

Comment: @M132 Q: *share stdout between multiple processes* implicitly means processes on the same computer (which are unable to connect to network for some reason - e.g. because the source doesn't multiple connections) - and your description actually confirms that. A: *re-transmit network stream*. They just don't match. If that answer is what you were looking for, Q's title should be something like *how to re-transmit TCP stream stream from server allowing just one connection* with the body updated accordingly (btw, it doesn't actually have to be TCP, it could be e.g. UDP as well).

Comment: @peterph _It listens for incoming connections on a certain port, and **any data read from standard input** is forwarded to those connections._ So the answer is _stream stdout over TCP_

Comment: @M132 I understand what the answer is about. All I'm saying is that if that is the answer you were looking for, the question is incorrectly posed. For me it truly is remarkable, that brm was able to infer what you were asking about from the question as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the [tcpclone](https://bitbucket.org/brmtron/tcpclone) tool can help you. It listens for incoming connections on a certain port, and any data read from standard input is forwarded to those connections.

Your example should then become something like this:

```
$ nc 111.222.233.244 1234 | ./tcpclone 5555 &
$ nc 127.0.0.1 5555
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem entirely, but how about:

```
$ nc 111.222.233.244 1234 \
    | tee -a /tmp/stream.dump \
    | while ! do_something_here; do : ; done
```

Apart from the obvious dumping of the stream into file with `tee` (appending, since network can be disconnected for various reasons and you mightn't necessarily want to overwrite previus part of the stream), this will respawn `do_somehing_here` unless it exits properly. Hence, if `do_somehing_here` is for example a wrapper script, you can kill whatever it actually calls, which makes the script exit abnormally and be re-spawned right away. If you edit the script before killing it, the processing of the stream can be changed without reconnecting.

Comment: Well, I want to use programs like ffmpeg, aplay and sometimes cat | grep, so it won't work properly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And why would that be? Anything that can handle the stream by syncing to some header therein should be fine. At least for me it works reasonably with a MP3.

Comment: Can I change script without killing processes started by it?

Comment: Sure - once the script is running, it is not read again (well, it probably might be under some extremely very heavy loads, but that's unlikely your case). Change the script to your liking, then kill the running process somehow (either its entire process subtree or something in the subtree that will cause the entire script to terminate - usually the first process in a pipe should do it), and it will be run again - this time the edited version.